# App which uses protobuf 2.6 doesn't run on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, qt, mir

I have a Qt app which statically links against protobuf 2.6.

When I try to run it on Ubuntu 17.10, I get an exception on startup.

> ```
> [libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program requires 
> version 3.0.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version
>  is 2.6.1.  
>
> Please update your library.  
>
> If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the 
> same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  
>
> (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-y44crS/mir-0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1/
>  obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
> ```

Looking at a stack trace, I see that the source of the exception is a protobuf file called `mir_protobuf.pb.cc` in `libmirprotobuf.so.3`

```
#8  google::protobuf::internal::VerifyVersion (headerVersion=3000000, minLibraryVersion=<optimized out>, filename=0x7f56e740fb00 "/build/mir-y44crS/mir-0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc") at google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61
#9  0x00007f56e73dd2bb in mir::protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_mir_5fprotobuf_2eproto() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
#10 0x00007f56e73d0109 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
```

Deeper in the stack trace I see this is being called by Qt, via `libqgtk3.so`

```
#16 0x00007f56f9cde0d9 in _dl_open (file=0x55c572496638 "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk3.so", mode=-2147479551, caller_dlopen=0x7f56f840571c, nsid=-2, argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, env=0x7ffe60c11c38) at dl-open.c:660
...
#23 0x00007f56f83ef068 in QFactoryLoader::instance(int) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

protobuf 3 is installed by default on Ubuntu 17.10

```
libmirprotobuf3/artful,now 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libprotobuf-dev/artful,now 3.0.0-9ubuntu5 amd64 [installed]
libprotobuf-lite10/artful,now 3.0.0-9ubuntu5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libprotobuf10/artful,now 3.0.0-9ubuntu5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

My app is statically linking against protobuf 2.6, but it seems this is interfering with `libmirprotobuf.so.3`.

Is it possible to run my app on Ubuntu 17.10?